# convert a Numpy Array to datetime.date pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a `numpy.ndarray` thats values are `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp`

Example:

In:  `type(closedDate)`

Out: `numpy.ndarray`

In:  `type(closedDate[0])`

Out: `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp`

I would like to convert the contents of `closedDate` into a list of `datetime.date`

I have tried the following:

```
for i in closedDate:
    closedDate[i].to_datetime()
```

But get this error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

What to do? :/

Comment: closedDate is a numpy array not a pandas df so `closedDate.values` would raise an error @Ami Tavory also the existing question of this deals with pandas df at first, whereas mine is a numpy array, so it is not a duplicate :P

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(closedDate, unit='s')`

Comment: `ValueError: non convertible value 2017-09-25 14:39:00with the unit 's'
` i get this error @Ami Tavory

Comment: It would help if you'd post a sample of the input in the question.

Comment: Just to address your error message (which doesn't have anything to do with your type casting): you mixed iterating over indices and iterating over elements. Either `for cd in closedDate: cd.to_datetime()` or `for i in range(len(closedDate)): closedDate[i].to_datetime()`. However, none oft these loops would be meaningful as the values aren't saved in a list vor wherever, just calculated for nothing. And besides: such loops are best written with one thing I really linke in Python: `for i, cd in enumerate(closedDate): ...` - this provides you both the elements and the indices in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect numpy to provide this functionality via `astype`, so you would not even have to loop over the array explicitely:

```
dt_arr = closedDate.astype(np.datetime64)
```

check:

```
closedDate
Out: 
array([Timestamp('2017-09-25 14:39:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-26 14:39:00'),
   Timestamp('2017-09-27 14:39:00')], dtype=object)

type(closedDate)
Out: numpy.ndarray

type(closedDate[0])
Out: pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp

type(dt_arr)
Out: numpy.ndarray

type(dt_arr[0])
Out: numpy.datetime64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.to_pydatetime().date() for x in closedDate]
```

Note, however, that you've probably made some kind of mistake to end up with a numpy array containing a pandas datatype. pandas Series and DataFrames are better equipped to handle pandas-specific types than numpy arrays are.